# Describing Predicate with C++ Concepts TS

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, c++-concepts

Imagine the implementation of `std::all_of` in a future C++ standard as such:

```
// constraining InputIt doesn't concern this question
template<typename InputIt, typename Pred>
bool all_of(InputIt first, InputIt last, Pred pred)
    requires Predicate<Pred, decltype(*first)>() 
    // requires Predicate<Pred>() // this would accept any, would like this
{
    for (; first != last; ++first)
        if (!pred(*first))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Where the concept `Predicate` is defined as:

```
template<typename Pred, typename Param>
concept bool Predicate()
{
    return requires(Pred p, Param a) {
        { p(a) } -> bool;
    };
}
```

This obviously works as intended. (Also when the function object has defaulted parameters, but isn't that still technically an UnaryPredicate?)

Anyway, having to specify the type which the predicate accepts can sometimes be a burden.

Is there a way to implement such a concept which would return `true` for function objects taking one or more parameters of *any* type where the type isn't explicitly specified?

Comment: Can you give an example of when it's a burden?  Not entirely clear to me which cases are giving you trouble.  Are you asking for a predicate that accepts [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)?

Comment: is this definition of Predicate concept from standard lib(libstdC++/libc++) or it's yours?

Comment: @BrianRodriguez It already seems kind of a burden in the above example. Nor very beginner friendly I guess. Plus it wouldn't be possible if there wasn't an `InputIt` available. And to answer your second question, not `std::any` specifically, but rather `template<class... Tn>` where `sizeof...(Tn) == 1`.

Comment: If your predicate already accepts a template parameter, then you wouldn't need to specify any types.  For example, this lambda can take any type but you don't have to explicitly list any of them: `std::all_of(any_container.begin(), any_container.end(), [](auto any_value) { return true; });`  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @BrianRodriguez No, you misunderstand. I edited the question. It's about the `requires` clause of the `all_of` implementation.

Comment: either i misunderstand question or your expectations are weird, concept cant "return" `true`, only `bool` it works on type level, not value level

Comment: @OlegBogdanov Well the terms are `variable concept` and `function concept` (or maybe the other way around). I'm assuming the function version `returns`, since something like `bool b = Concept<T>();` is well-formed.

Comment: What's the use case for this? Why does it matter if a type has a `bool operator()(unnameable_internal_type_42 const volatile&&);`?

Comment: @T.C. So would you say the above is a valid implementation of the concept? It pretty much works like std::is_callable this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to implement such a concept which would return true for function objects taking one or more parameters of any type where the type isn't explicitly specified?

I don't think there's a reasonable way to express this. Maybe with the reflection proposal it is possible to check that a function object accepts only arguments that are either `auto` or, equivalently, a plain template parameter `T`.

Regarding:

```
// requires Predicate<Pred>() // this would accept any, would like this
```

Concepts test properties of types, so you actually need to specify the argument type `A` for which a type `P` should satisfy `Predicate<P,A>()`. If you could do this without specifying `A`, then `Predicate` could not check the specified constraints between `P` and `A`, which is what concepts are for.